# Javascript: update a column in matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I want to update an entire column of a matrix.

I started by initializing the matrix like:

```
    m =({length:10}, (_,i) => Array.from({length:2}, (_,j) => i+'x'+j));
```

Then, I have an array of 2 element (say, a2) that I want to put in the j-th column of the matrix with manipulation. 
If I am using matlab I would do the following: `m(:,j)=a2+ m(:,j)`

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?:

```js
const m = Array.from({length:10}, (_,i) => Array.from({length:2}, (_,j) => i+'x'+j));

console.log("before", m);

const j = 2;
const a2 = "z"
const n = m.map(row => {row.splice(j, 0, a2); return row});

console.log("after", n);
```

before manipulation:

```js
before [
  [    "0x0",    "0x1"  ],
  [    "1x0",    "1x1"  ],
  [    "2x0",    "2x1"  ],
  [    "3x0",    "3x1"  ],
  [    "4x0",    "4x1"  ],
  [    "5x0",    "5x1"  ],
  [    "6x0",    "6x1"  ],
  [    "7x0",    "7x1"  ],
  [    "8x0",    "8x1"  ],
  [    "9x0",    "9x1"  ]
]
```

And after manipulation (i.e. add "z" to column 2):

```js
after [
  [    "0x0",    "0x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "1x0",    "1x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "2x0",    "2x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "3x0",    "3x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "4x0",    "4x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "5x0",    "5x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "6x0",    "6x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "7x0",    "7x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "8x0",    "8x1",    "z"  ],
  [    "9x0",    "9x1",    "z"  ]
]
```

Or if `a2` should be an array itself? Then, the simple case that it is a 1D array:

```js
const m = Array.from({length:10}, (_,i) => Array.from({length:2}, (_,j) => i+'x'+j));

console.log("before", m);

const j = 2;
const a2 = Array.from({length:10}, (_,j) => 'z'+j)
const n = m.map((row, i) => {row.splice(j, 0, a2[i]); return row});

console.log("after", n);
```

After manipulation (i.e. add "z{ i }" to column 2):

```js
after [
  [    "0x0",    "0x1",    "z0"  ],
  [    "1x0",    "1x1",    "z1"  ],
  [    "2x0",    "2x1",    "z2"  ],
  [    "3x0",    "3x1",    "z3"  ],
  [    "4x0",    "4x1",    "z4"  ],
  [    "5x0",    "5x1",    "z5"  ],
  [    "6x0",    "6x1",    "z6"  ],
  [    "7x0",    "7x1",    "z7"  ],
  [    "8x0",    "8x1",    "z8"  ],
  [    "9x0",    "9x1",    "z9"  ]
]
```

Or the more complex case when `a2` is a 2D array:

```js
const m = Array.from({length:10}, (_,i) => Array.from({length:2}, (_,j) => i+'x'+j));

console.log("before", m);

const j = 2;
const a2 = Array.from({length:10}, (_,i) => Array.from({length:2}, (_,j) => i+'z'+j));
const n = m.map((row, i) => {row.splice(j, 0, a2[i]); return row.flat()});

console.log("after", n);
```

After manipulation (i.e. add "z{ i }" to column 2):

```js
after [
  [    "0x0",    "0x1",    "0z0",    "0z1"  ],
  [    "1x0",    "1x1",    "1z0",    "1z1"  ],
  [    "2x0",    "2x1",    "2z0",    "2z1"  ],
  [    "3x0",    "3x1",    "3z0",    "3z1"  ],
  [    "4x0",    "4x1",    "4z0",    "4z1"  ],
  [    "5x0",    "5x1",    "5z0",    "5z1"  ],
  [    "6x0",    "6x1",    "6z0",    "6z1"  ],
  [    "7x0",    "7x1",    "7z0",    "7z1"  ],
  [    "8x0",    "8x1",    "8z0",    "8z1"  ],
  [    "9x0",    "9x1",    "9z0",    "9z1"  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.splice` is a good way to accomplish this:

```js
// Setup for demo
const Row = (w) =>Array.from({length:w}).fill('').map((c,i)=>c=i);
const Matrix = (h, w) => Array.from({length:h}).fill('').map(r=>r=Row(w));
const print = (mtx) => mtx.forEach(r=>console.log([...r].join(", ")));

// Original state of matrix
const m1 = Matrix(2,10);
print(m1);
console.log('----------');

// Insertion function
const insertCol = (mtx, cInd, newCol) => {
  mtx.forEach( (row, rInd) => { row.splice(cInd, 0, newCol[rInd]); }
  );
}

// Matrix with inserted column
const someCol = ['X','Y'];
insertCol(m1, 3, someCol);
print(m1);
```